# What would this being's 'voice' sound like?

Tags: science-based, physics

I have a being that does not have vocal cords, and instead, speaks to 3-dimensional beings(humans) by manipulating air to produce what sounds like human speech. What would its voice sound like?

Comment: I have on my desk two magical machines called *speakers* which don't have vocal chords, but manipulate air pressure to produce what sounds like human speech. The sound they make sounds exactly like human speech, and more often than not they produce sound which sounds like exceedingly beautiful human voices, such as the voices of famous sopranos or singers of popular music.

Answer (score 8):

If he's adept, he'd sound like a human on a high-quality audio system.

All sound, including speech, is the result of vibrations in the air.  There is no difference between vocal cords, [cone speakers](https://www.google.com/search?q=cone+speakers&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrpeXknMLZAhVM6mMKHe_MDYoQsAQIJg&biw=1600&bih=1058), and your "manipulating air to produce sound" being because they all "manipulate air to produce sound."

So, "vocal" quality is the result of how adept the being is at manipulating the air.  If he's good, he sounds like Bing Crosby.  If he's not, he sounds like an [early Apple II speech synthesizer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3QV_2hq8qU).